# Drink Recipe Database

Tags: data-request, food, recipes

I'm looking for a free/open Drink (Cocktail) Recipe database. I found this one: http://www.odditysoftware.com/page-datasales7.htm which looks like exactly what I want, but this project doesn't have the budget to buy a database like this. Is there anything free that can get me close?

Answer (score 5):

The Wikimedia project Wikibooks has a book on bartending, including a full [chapter of cocktail recipes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bartending/Cocktails). Not a database, but pretty comprehensive and possibly a good start for a proper database.

Answer (score 4):

I found a wiki with many coctails recipes and extra info, but since I can see, it has a strict copyright. Maybe you can contact with them, if you want the database for non-commercial use.

[Webtender.com](http://wiki.webtender.com/wiki/Category%3aRecipes)

Answer (score 4):

I would be really surprised if such a data set existed. Prices will vary depending of your location and/or country. I think the best for you is to merge your source with a price index source.

For example here in Ontario, LCBO  (the provincial monopoly selling alcohol) information have been made available through an [API](http://lcboapi.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You might look at the source for Bartendro - https://github.com/partyrobotics - there is a default drink DB and I know there has been at least some community interest in building a more comprehensive open drink database.